# Login via session via ahref?

Tags: php, mysql, session

firstly let me state that I'm fiarly new with coding, have been doing it for bout half a year actively now, however.

I've come to run into a problem, and I'm not able to find any solution here, or there.

What I wanted to make:

1. Make a user that everybody can access by clicking on a hyperlink (ahref)
2. Make it login to this account once you click on the link
3. This all has to happen in a session

However, I got stuck at the very last part, mostly also cause I want to hide data.

So I've createdmy user, gave it a password, made the link, and a session will start, however, I'm not able to transfer this link into actually logging in, as in how do I make it send the username + password automatically?

Answer (score 0):

via javascript you can use an onLoad event if i remember correctly to make this javascript make a post request.
the other way would be to hash the password as md5(or whatever you use to save them in the db) and make it a normal link with get parameters like http://localhost/home.php?func=login&username=foo&password=md5(bar)

Comment: Thank you I will look into this tonight and see if I can make it work, thanks a lot for the fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create a demo user for the appliacation

create a dedicated login function for this user, it won't take any parameters and will have hardcoded username and password in the function's body

e.g you'll have standardLoginFunction(username, password) and demoLoginFunction() with body:

```
demoLoginFunction() {
    demo_username = demo;
    demo_password = demo;
    standardLoginFunction(demo_username, demo_password);
}
```

now you bind the demoLoginFunction to the appropriate element of your website, this way you don't reveal any data to the site's visitors

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the link 'simulate' your login logic. For example, if your login link would look like: login.php?key=KnockKnock, your login.php script would have to do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['key']) && $_GET['key'] == 'KnockKnock') {
    // Login triggered
    $user = 'global';
    $password = 'secret';

    // From here, continue with your "default" logic, like:
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "'" .
             " AND `password`='" . md5($password) . "' LIMIT 1";
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query)) == 1) {
        // User found!
        session_start();
        // Rest of logic here
    }
}
```

That's in a nutshell a **very simplified** procedure for doing automated logins using a link

Comment: Awesome, and easely to implement, will let you know if this will work out for me, I'm going to try it out tonight after I finish work. thanks a lot!

Comment: If possible migrate to a better alternative than MD5 or also SHA-1, which are considered insecure nowadays.

Comment: @MatthiasDieterWallnöfer True, but this example is very outdated anyway. mysql_ functions don't even exist anymore.